$ T $ is a linear operator show it is bounded and has extension in Hilbert space.
I am new to functional analysis and encountered this problem.
Let $ \mathcal{H} $ be a separable Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis $ \{v_n\}_{n \geq 1} $. Let $ \{q_1, q_2, \ldots\} $ be an enumeration of $ \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1] $. Consider the dense subspace $ D = \text{span}\{v_n \mid n \geq 1\} $ in $ \mathcal{H} $ and the map $ T: D \to \mathcal{H} $ defined by
$$ T\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k v_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k q_k v_{k} $$
where $ a_k $ are in $ \mathbb{C} $ such that only finitely many are nonzero.
$\textbf{Show that:}$
A.  $ T $ is a linear operator and has extension on whole $\mathcal{H}$.
B.  $ T $ is not compact.
My work:
For A. is it sufficient to show that the image is $D$ is dense?
For B. since image is not finite dimensional it is not compact(Is this argument correct)
$D$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$.
We can choose  $a_k$in such a way that image becomes dense in $\mathcal{H}$.
Then there exist $\tilde{T}:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ such that
it coincides with $T$ on $D$.

Recall that for any $ x \in D $:
$$ \| x \|^2 = \left\| \sum_{k \geq 1} a_k v_k \right\|^2 = \sum_{k \geq 1} |a_k|^2 $$

Then,

$$ \| T(x) \|^2 = \left\| \sum_{k \geq 1} a_k q_k v_k \right\|^2 = \sum_{k \geq 1} |a_k q_k|^2 $$

Since $ |q_k| \leq 1 $ for all $ k $:

$$ \| T(x) \|^2 \leq \sum_{k \geq 1} |a_k|^2 = \| x \|^2 $$


How to show $\tilde{T}$ is bounded using all these things.

Please specify: what do you mean by extension to H? A bounded, linear extension? Because that is not clear but suggested by your headline

What is $v_{q_k}$ ? Perhaps you meant $v_k.$

Yes sorry @RyszardSzwarc

@TimonKolt here the operator defined on $D$ we want an operator of $\mathcal{H}$ such that it coincides when we are at $D$

The range of $T$ is not dense, unless you consider $\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1]$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1].$

How you can say that @RyszardSzwarc

Ok if i assume range is not dense then this shows my thinking is incorrect.

@RyszardSzwarc can you explain why considering  $\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1]$  makes image dense.

We have $q_{k_0}=0$ for some $k_0.$ Hence the range of $T$ is orthogonal to $v_{k_0}.$ The same holds for the extension of $T$ as $\overline{R(T)}= \overline{R(\tilde{T})}.$
Let's consider $\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1].$ Then $Tv_n=q_nv_n\neq 0.$ Hence $v_n\in R(T)$ for every $n.$ Thus ${\rm span}\,{v_n}_{n=1}^\infty $ is contained in $R(T).$ Therefore $R(T)$ is dense.
Every number $q_n$ is an eigenvalue of $T,$ thus also of its extension. Hence the operator $\tilde{T}$ is not compact. For compact operators the eigenvalues may concentrate only at $0.$
Another straightforward argument: let $q_{n_k}$ denote the eigenvalues such that ${1\over 2}\le q_{n_k}\le 1.$ The sequence $v_{n_k}$ is bounded. But the sequence $Tv_{n_k}=q_{n_k}v_{n_k}$ does not admit a convergent subsequence as $$\|Tv_{n_k}-Tv_{n_l}\|^2=q_{n_k}^2+q_{n_l}^2\ge {1\over 2}$$ provided that $n_k\neq n_l.$

what do you mean by eigen value concentrate at 0.

The sequence of nonzero eigenvalues tend to $0$ or there are finitely many nonzero eigenvalues.

You may say eigen values are finite for compact operators.

Isnt there any elementary method for to proove that operator is not compact.
